# Rspec expect method to receive ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

I have a method

`foo(bars)`

`bars` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`

In my spec I want to assert that `foo` is called with `bars` but in the spec `bars` is just an array

```
let(:bar) { create(:bar) }
let(:bars) { [bar] }

expect(described_class).to receive(:foo).with(bars)
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I can't stub `bars` within the controller as I am testing the filtering of `bars` based on `params` passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of faking bars, you could check that bars is the value you expect:

```
expect(described_class).to receive(:foo) do |bars|
    # verify bars here. You could do bars.to_a and check the array 
    # or bars.to_sql and check the generated sql.
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set an expectation on something and still have it run the original code. Just add `and_call_original` to your expectation:

```
expect(described_class).to receive(:foo).with(bars).and_call_original
```

Details from the documentation available here: http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-4/docs/configuring-responses/calling-the-original-implementation

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like `let(:bars) { BarClass.where(id: [bar.id]) }`, so expected `bars` are also  `ActiveRecord::Relation`. But it did not work, because of `ActiveRecord::Relation#==` method. My `expected` have different SQL than `actual` ones.

```
From: gems/activerecord-6.0.2.1/lib/active_record/relation.rb @ line 682:
Owner: ActiveRecord::Relation
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 10

def ==(other)
  case other
  when Associations::CollectionProxy, AssociationRelation
    self == other.records
  when Relation
    other.to_sql == to_sql
  when Array
    records == other
  end
end
```

but in search in RSPEC code, I find , that `.with()` accepts block. Not directly but on `receive`. As @Jeff F. already wrote.

And because I need stub returned value on `export` method, it all ends as:

```
exporter_double = instance_double(Xml::Exporter::InventoriesExporter, export: "<xml>Result of export to POHODA for [#{inventories.collect(&:code).join(',')}]</xml>")
expect(Xml::Exporter::InventoriesExporter).to receive(:new) do |arg1, arg2, arg3|
        # doing my own `.with(inventories, :xml, {})` because actual `inventories` is ActiveRecord::Relation, not array
        expect(arg1.to_a).to eq(inventories)
        expect(arg2).to be(:xml)
        expect(arg3).to eq({})
end.and_return(exporter_double)
```